# Calc() in animation css property is not working in only microsft edge

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations, microsoft-edge, css-calc

This loader animation is working fine in Chrome, Opera, Firefox and Safari too. But not working in Microsoft Edge. Is it possible to make it work in Edge?

```
<div class="_preLoader" style="--n:5">
            <div class="_circle _c1" style="--i:0"></div>
            <div class="_circle _c2" style="--i:1"></div>
            <div class="_circle _c3" style="--i:2"></div>
            <div class="_circle _c4" style="--i:3"></div>
            <div class="_circle _c5" style="--i:4"></div>
        </div>
```

STYLE

```
._preloader {
        display: flex;
        align-content: space-around;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    ._circle,
    ._circle::after {
        background: rgb(255, 99, 71);
        display: inline-block;
        width: 2em;
        height: 2em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        animation: a 1s calc(((var(--i) + var(--o, 0))/var(--n) - 1)*1s) infinite
    }


    ._circle::after {
        --o: 1;
        background: #3C4252;
        content: ''
    }



    @keyframes a {
        0%,
        50% {
            transform: scale(0)
        }
```

This jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/03ddygdx/20/ shows the animation in the described browsers perfectly except microsft edge.

Comment: a mix of variable and calc, I am not surprised that Microsoft fail .. too complex for them ...

Comment: You wrote a statement not a question, you're letting us know something doesn't work across browsers. What is the question? Can it work on Edge? Is it a compatibility issue? Is there an alternate way of achieveing the same using different css techinques?

Comment: seems this is a known issue. but microsoft just won't fix it https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/105834/